# value / is not a member of sbt.librarymanagement.ModuleID

Tags: scala, scala.js

I face this error: -

```
value / is not a member of sbt.librarymanagement.ModuleID
```

when defining in Dependencies.scala: -

```
"org.webjars.npm" % "long" % "4.0.0" / "long.js" commonJSName "Long"
```

Can anybody help me in this?

Note:- I have already imported **ScalaJSPlugin.autoImport** :-

```
import org.scalajs.sbtplugin.ScalaJSPlugin.autoImport._
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `jsDependencies` mechanism, and everything related to it, has been moved to a separate sbt plugin [`sbt-jsdependencies`](https://github.com/scala-js/jsdependencies) for the Scala.js 1.x series.

You will need to add it in `project/plugins.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("org.scala-js" % "sbt-jsdependencies" % "1.0.2")
```

and, if using `project/*.scala` files, as it seems you're doing, you will need the following import in those:

```
import org.scalajs.jsdependencies.sbtplugin.JSDependenciesPlugin.autoImport._
```